# Why not upvote the question count automatically every time any answer is upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, voting, up-votes

Regardless of which answer is useful to a viewer, if an answer is upvoted, the question should automatically be upvoted as well.  Obviously the answer would not be posted unless the question existed.

It should also be possible to upvote the question even if there is no acceptable answer, but limit the upvote of the question to 1 per viewer.

Comment: This is a bad thing on meta sites. The community can disagree with a particular feature suggestion in a question, and agree with an answer that explains why the feature isn't something that should be implemented. Upvoting an answer can mean the exact opposite as upvoting the question.

Comment: ...and even on main sites. A question might be lacking research effort, poorly written, etc., and then someone comes and posts an awesome answer. That kind of question deserves a downvote. We shouldn't upvote it just because it got answered. And we also shouldn't deprive the answerer of getting a well-deserved upvote just because they answered an on-topic question that happens to have other problems.

Comment: _"It should also be possible to upvote the question even if there is no acceptable answer"_ That is possible right now.

Comment: Is the reason behind this feature request is because you're concerned that users might upvote answers that have helped them but not pay attention to the question? If so, note that if one has a habit of voting on answers only, they would get a reminder every now and then saying "You haven't voted on questions in a while". It's probably not the best solution but it gives users a chance to reconsider how to spend their votes.

Comment: @41686d6564  I understand that, I just wanted to be clear that I didn't intend to have that changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatically upvoting questions when someone upvotes one (or more) of the question’s answers is not a good idea because on Stack Exchange posts should be judged based on their content, not other posts' content. A good question can have terrible answers, and a mediocre question can have great answers. Mechanisms that cause people to look at factors other than the content of a post when deciding how to vote on it are not good for SE. If I know that upvoting an answer will upvote the question, I will take that into consideration when deciding whether to upvote the answer or not, and that is not fair to the author of the answer.

If a question was automatically upvoted when an answer to it is upvoted, then it would only be fair if answers were downvoted when the question was downvoted, so that answering low quality questions is discouraged. But it's not constructive to downvote good content because an author tried to help someone who posted an unloved question. Askers are rewarded when they get a great answer to their question. It's not fair to also reward them for the quality of someone else's work. If they want reputation as a reward, they need to earn it the same way that the answerers do—by providing good quality content. (I'm aware that the reality is sometimes different than what the system was designed to be, but that is not a reason to stop working toward post scores being based solely on the quality and correctness of the content.)

Comment: I think the general public upvotes an answer when they use it in their life -- thus the question is clearly something that they themselves are asking.  And I think the general public down votes an answer only when it doesn't work or is wrong.  Indeed, a down vote still implies that the question is relevant.